# Calling .dll method using C#

Tags: c#, dll

I am pretty new to .dll stuffs, however, I have been assigned a task in which I have to call a method from .dll file using C#. I am completely new to these stuffs. So can someone point me in the right direction regarding this.
Thanks

Comment: Add reference to the .dll file from within Visual Studio by right clicking References in the proper project then use its namespace. You will even have auto complete. This of course assuming that DLL was compiled by .NET framework. (Doesn't have to be C#)

Comment: Does the DLL need to be loaded dynamically or can it be loaded with the project?

Comment: why type of dll? activex, com? if none of these, than try with pinvoke
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @cichy that one is better http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

Comment: Is it a .NET dll or a dll created using some native language like C or C++?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a .NET dll, Load the DLL via [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) (or [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx)) 
and then call [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) and then for each type call [Type.GetMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx). When you have a [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx), you can call [MethodInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx) on it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a native non-net dll like kernel32.dll:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
```

Then just call e.g. AttachConsole like a normal Function.

Comment: Do i need to copy this dll in project anywhere?

Comment: If its a dll which can be reached by path: no. If its a dll located elsewhere, then either path needs to be adjusted or dll copied. If using system dll's, read something about "dll-hell" to learn about some problems with those...